# mypy spurious error: "module" has no attribute "XPath" with etree

Tags: python, lxml, mypy

I'm trying to use `mypy` to do type checking in some code that uses the [LXML](http://lxml.de/) library to parse XML.

On each line where I use `etree.XPath`, I get a spurious error from `mypy`.  For example, the following trivial script

```
from lxml import etree    
NameXPath = etree.XPath("Name/text()")
```

generates the error

```
test.py:3: error: "module" has no attribute "XPath"
```

But the script runs fine and my `XPath`'s work correctly at runtime.

I also tried `#type:ignore` on the import, which I thought might tell `mypy` not to type-check that library, but that did not suppress the errors.

```
from lxml import etree # type:ignore    
NameXPath = etree.XPath("Name/text()")
```

I did have some success at suppressing some of the errors by moving the calls to `etree.XPath` into a separate function which doesn't have any type annotations, but that seemed like a hack and forced me to arrange my code in awkward ways.

I would like to know if there's a way to completely suppress these spurious errors, or to possibly hint that the `etree.XPath` function does exist since it doesn't seem to be able to figure that out on its own.

To be clear, I don't actually care that `mypy` knows the correct types for structures coming out of the `lxml` library.  I'm more concerned about putting the type info on my own classes that I'm shoving the parsed information into, so I want to have type-checked functions which use `etree.XPath` to do queries, find the data, and then shove them into type-annotated classes that are defined within my script.

`mypy` doesn't seem to have difficulty with other functions in `etree`, for example it's fine with my calls to `etree.parse`

I'm currently using `mypy` 0.4.4

Answer (score 12):

It looks like this is a bug in [typeshed](https://github.com/python/typeshed), the community-contributed collection of type annotations for the stdlib and various third party libraries.

In particular, it looks as if the [stubs for lxml](https://github.com/python/typeshed/tree/master/third_party/3/lxml) are missing definitions for XPath entirely. This is probably an oversight -- I would try filing a bug on the issue tracker or try submitting a pull request containing a fix.

Once this is fixed, and mypy resyncs itself with the latest version of typeshed, you'll need to install mypy from the [git repo](https://github.com/python/mypy) for the time being (at least, until mypy 0.4.5 comes out sometime in October).

In the meantime, you can work around this by doing this:

```
from lxml.etree import XPath  # type: ignore
NameXPath = XPath("Name/text()")
# mypy considers NameXPath to have a type of Any
```

...or, if you'd prefer having a more specific definition of XPath, do this:

```
import typing

if typing.TYPE_CHECKING:
    # typing.TYPE_CHECKING is always False at runtime, so this
    # branch is parsed by typecheckers only
    class XPath:
        # Provide a method header stubs with signatures to fool
        # mypy into understanding what the interface for XPath is
else:
    # Actually executed at runtime
    from lxml.etree import XPath  # type: ignore

NameXPath = XPath("Name/text()")
```

Comment: Thanks.  your first suggestion of using "import XPath # type:ignore" worked.  I assumed incorrectly that using "import etree" #type:ignore would make it ignore types for anything within etree, but this is not the case.   I don't know enough to write the type annotations needed in your second suggestion or to propose a patch to typeshed, but I did submit a [bug](https://github.com/python/typeshed/issues/525) on there